# How can I change the texture in a Blender model loaded into three.js, after it's been loaded, with ImageUtils.loadTexture?

Tags: three.js, textures, blender

I'm doing a student project at involves a gift box where users can change how it looks.

I started learning what to do by making a cube, importing a texture and setting a gui.dat control to allow the user to change the texture.

I'm now trying to replace the cube with a blender model of a gift box but I'm having trouble changing the texture.

EDIT: The full code is on github here: 
https://github.com/GitKiwi/GiftBox/blob/master/Workspace/Proto%208c%20Changing%20textures%20on%20giftbox.html

The coding for the working cube model is:

`// add cube with texture

```
    var cubeGeometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(4,4,4);
    var cubeMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ map:
             THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture("birthday.jpg") });
    var cube = new THREE.Mesh(cubeGeometry,cubeMaterial);

    cube.position.set (0,0,0);
    cube.rotation.set (0,-1.2,0);
    cube.receiveShadow  = true;

    // add the cube to scene
    scene.add(cube); `
```

//gui texture change

```
`var controls = new function()
{ this.changeTexture = "birthday";

this.changeTexture = function (e){
var texture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture
("../assets/textures/general/" + e + ".jpg");
cube.material.map = texture; }`
```

//gui control

```
var gui = new dat.GUI();
gui.add(controls, "changeTexture", ['christmas', 'valentine', 'birthday']).onChange(controls.changeTexture);
```

I'm loading the gift box in four parts and I'm just trying to get the first part, the box, to change texture. I load it with:

```
var box;
    var loaderOne = new THREE.JSONLoader();

    loaderOne.load('../assets/models/box.js', function (geometry)
    {
        var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0xffff00});
        box = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
        box.position.set (5,0,5);
        box.scale.set (1,1,1);
        //box.name = "mybox";
        scene.add(box);
    });
```

I can't get it to change texture with the gui control. I've tried changing the "cube" to "box" in the gui texture change code and I've tried naming the box and calling it(commented out in the code above) but those didn't work. I've searched for answers to this in a number of places but I'm just really stuck. I feel I'm perhaps missing something obvious?

Any help to would really be appreciated.

Comment: Did you set `texture.needsUpdate = true` after setting `material.map = texture;`?

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work. It works for the cube without that line but when I try to change the box texture, with or without that line it doesn't work.

Comment: You need to show your entire code, not snippets. Can you provide a live example?

Comment: I will go and clean up my folders and code and post it in github then link it here. It's getting a little late where I am so I will do this tomorrow morning, otherwise I'll make sleepy mistakes. Thank you for taking the time to look over my code.

Comment: I've EDITED the original question and added in a link to the full code on github. If the word "box" on line 122 is changed to "cube" the cube  texture can be correctly changed through the gui. Changing the box does not currently work.

Comment: @WestLangley I've been looking at this problem some more today because the model does not work with tweening either. Because I found that the model can appear correctly without "var box;" being declared, I wonder if the model is not being loaded into the box variable, outside the loader, and this is why I cannot manipulate it. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I can answer questions about three.js, but I can't help you debug your code. There are a lot of moving parts in your code that could be causing you problems.

Comment: @WestLangley - Ok, thanks for looking at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code wasn't working because there were no texture maps for the model I was importing.

What I did was go back to Blender and create a model with two textures that could each be applied to the whole model. The exported JSON file then had the model geometry and the two textures (with their texture maps).

In three.js I loaded it:

```
// load in geometry and textures
    var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
    loader.load('../models/two textures on cube.js', function (geometry, material)
    {
        matOne = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial(material[1]);
        matTwo = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial(material[2]);
        box = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, matOne);

        //position, scale
        box.position.set (0,0,0);
        box.rotation.set (0,-1.2,0);
        box.scale.set (2,2,2);
        box.receiveShadow  = true;
        scene.add(box);


    }, '../models');
```

and then used this code to switch the textures:

```
//gui control panel
    var controls = new function()
    {                   
        //changing the texture
        this.changeTexture = function (e)
        {
        switch (e) 
            {
        case "birthday":
        box.material = matOne;
        break;

        case "christmas":
        box.material = matTwo;
        break;
            }
        }
    }
```

with this code for the gui.dat controls:

```
//gui control panel
    var gui = new dat.GUI();
    gui.add(controls, "changeTexture", ['birthday', 'christmas']).onChange(controls.changeTexture);
```